# XCC .Net Upload File problems

Tags: marklogic

We use the XCC .Net Library to upload files through a web service. 99% of the time the process works fine, but that 1% doesn't make sense. It's typically a pdf file that has been scanned in (not always, but most times). The file that gets placed up on the server is usually double in size (1.2 meg becomes 2.5) and is corrupted. When i place the file on the server using webdav everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help without information. It does sound like you've narrowed the problem down to XCC vs webDAV, but that still leaves a fairly large range of possibilities.

- Which version of MarkLogic Server are you using?
- What OS is the server running on?
- Which version of .NET are you using?
- Which version of the .NET XCC client are you using?
- What OS is the client running on?

It would also be helpful to see your upload code.